# While cycle implementation never ends in Ply issue

Tags: python, while-loop, compiler-construction, yacc, ply

Im trying to implement a small programming language with **ply** in python 3.8, the problem is that my implementation of a **while loop** never stops, and it seems that the condition in **p[3]** is never updated, here is the statement:

```
def p_statement_if(p):
    '''statement : IF LPAREN comparison RPAREN LBRAKET statement RBRAKET
                 | IF LPAREN comparison RPAREN LBRAKET statement RBRAKET ELSE LBRAKET statement RBRAKET'''
    if p[3]:
        p[0] = p[6]
    else:
        if p[10] is not None:
            p[0] = p[10]

def p_statement_while(p):
    'statement : WHILE LPAREN comparison RPAREN LBRAKET statement RBRAKET'
    while(p[3]):
        p[0] = p[6]
```

My question is how can I keep it always updating the condition that is in **p[3]**?

my entire code is this:

```
tokens = (
    'NAME','NUMBER',
    'PLUS','MINUS','TIMES','DIVIDE','EQUALS',
    'LPAREN','RPAREN','LBRAKET','RBRAKET',
    'EQUAL','NOTEQ','LARGE','SMALL','LRGEQ','SMLEQ',
    'ENDSTM',
    )

reserved = {
    'while' : 'WHILE',
    'if'    : 'IF',
    'else'  : 'ELSE',
    'print' : "PRINT",
}
tokens += tuple(reserved.values())
# Tokens

t_PLUS    = r'\+'
t_MINUS   = r'-'
t_TIMES   = r'\*'
t_DIVIDE  = r'/'
t_EQUALS  = r'='

t_LPAREN  = r'\('
t_RPAREN  = r'\)'
t_LBRAKET  = r'\{'
t_RBRAKET  = r'\}'

t_EQUAL   = r'\=\='
t_NOTEQ   = r'\!\='
t_LARGE   = r'\>'
t_SMALL   = r'\<'
t_LRGEQ   = r'\>\='
t_SMLEQ   = r'\<\='

t_ENDSTM  = r';'

def t_NUMBER(t):
    r'\d+'
    t.value = int(t.value)
    return t

def t_NAME(t):
    r'[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*'
    if t.value in reserved:
        t.type = reserved[t.value]
    return t

# Ignored characters
t_ignore = " \t"

def t_newline(t):
    r'\n+'
    t.lexer.lineno += t.value.count("\n")

def t_error(t):
    print(f"Illegal character {t.value[0]!r}")
    t.lexer.skip(1)

# Build the lexer
import ply.lex as lex
lex.lex()

# Precedence rules for the arithmetic operators
precedence = (
    ('left','PLUS','MINUS'),
    ('left','TIMES','DIVIDE'),
    ('right','UMINUS'),
    )

# dictionary of names (for storing variables)
names = { }

def p_statement_statement(p):
    'statement : statement statement'

def p_statement_assign(p):
    'statement : NAME EQUALS expression ENDSTM'
    names[p[1]] = p[3]

def p_statement_expr(p):
    'statement : expression ENDSTM'
    print(p[1])

def p_expression_binop(p):
    '''expression : expression PLUS expression
                  | expression MINUS expression
                  | expression TIMES expression
                  | expression DIVIDE expression'''
    if p[2] == '+'  : p[0] = p[1] + p[3]
    elif p[2] == '-': p[0] = p[1] - p[3]
    elif p[2] == '*': p[0] = p[1] * p[3]
    elif p[2] == '/': p[0] = p[1] / p[3]

def p_comparison_binop(p):
    '''comparison : expression EQUAL expression
                  | expression NOTEQ expression
                  | expression LARGE expression
                  | expression SMALL expression
                  | expression LRGEQ expression
                  | expression SMLEQ expression'''
    if p[2] == '==':
        p[0] = p[1] == p[3]
    elif p[2] == '!=':
        p[0] = p[1] != p[3]
    elif p[2] == '>':
        p[0] = p[1] > p[3]
    elif p[2] == '<':
        p[0] = p[1] < p[3]
    elif p[2] == '>=':
        p[0] = p[1] >= p[3]
    elif p[2] == '<=':
        p[0] = p[1] <= p[3]

def p_statement_if(p):
    '''statement : IF LPAREN comparison RPAREN LBRAKET statement RBRAKET
                 | IF LPAREN comparison RPAREN LBRAKET statement RBRAKET ELSE LBRAKET statement RBRAKET'''
    if p[3]:
        p[0] = p[6]
    else:
        if p[10] is not None:
            p[0] = p[10]

def p_statement_while(p):
    'statement : WHILE LPAREN comparison RPAREN LBRAKET statement RBRAKET'
    while(p[3]):
        p[0] = p[6]

def p_statement_print(p):
    'statement : PRINT LPAREN expression RPAREN ENDSTM'
    print(p[3])

def p_expression_uminus(p):
    'expression : MINUS expression %prec UMINUS'
    p[0] = -p[2]

def p_expression_group(p):
    'expression : LPAREN expression RPAREN'
    p[0] = p[2]

def p_expression_number(p):
    'expression : NUMBER'
    p[0] = p[1]

def p_expression_name(p):
    'expression : NAME'
    try:
        p[0] = names[p[1]]
    except LookupError:
        print(f"Undefined name {p[1]!r}")
        p[0] = 0

def p_error(p):
    try:
        print(f"Syntax error at {p.value!r}")
    except:
        print("Error")

import ply.yacc as yacc
yacc.yacc()

s = open('input.txt','r').read()
yacc.parse(s)
```

The example input file **input.txt** has this:

```
a = 7;
b = a * 2;
print(a + b);
if(a<b){
    print(a);
}
while(a<b){
    a = a + 1;
    print(a);
}
```

and i got this output (never stops):

```
21
7
8
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ply does not change the rules of Python. It parses an input (**once**), producing whatever result you chose to implement in the parsing action functions. That's it.

So it's evident that you cannot write an immediate interpreter as parsing rules. Execution happens after a program is parsed, and there is not a one-to-one relationship between program code and execution: some expressions (like your `while` condition) are evaluated many times; other expressions (like the failed branches of `if-then-else` statements) are not evaluated at all. Functions are called, with different arguments each time; you cannot predict what the values of those arguments are when you compile the code.

The result of compiling a program is an "executable". That executable might be low-level machine code, or it might be some higher-level description of a program which explains what the program does when it is executed.

If all that seemed too hand-wavy, I strongly suggest that you work your way through Abelson & Sussman's *Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs*, which can be [read for free on-line](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sites/default/files/sicp/full-text/book/book.html) thanks to the generosity of its authors, and which almost 40 years after its initial publication, continues to be the best single-volume introduction to the *concepts* underlying computer programs. If you want to write an compiler (or an interpreter), start there.

Comment: Thank you i'll check the book. I didn't realize that in this case, i'm trying to make an interpreter instead a compiller, im so new in this area.